# How to make dot progressing in powershell windows form?

Tags: powershell, winforms, progress-bar

I need to build winform with some icon and make label and icon to represent each process. I got some problem to make the progress in each process. Here is my code:

```
#--- gui setting ---#
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

#--- create main form ---#
# get screen info, if multiple screen, get the primary one.
$screen_info = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens
$screen_width = $screen_info[0].WorkingArea.Width
$screen_height = $screen_width * (9 / 16) - 40

# main form cottingnfigurationnfiguration
$main_form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$main_form.Text = "Tool" #Form Title
$main_form.AutoSize = $True
$main_form.MaximizeBox = $false
$main_form.WindowState = "Normal"
$main_form.FormBorderStyle = "Fixed3D"
$main_form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$main_form.AutoScroll = $True
$main_form.Add_KeyDown( {
        if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
        { $main_form.Close() }
    }
)

# adjust screen size if < 1280
if ($screen_width -le 1280) {
    Write-Host "-le 1280"
    $main_form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( ($screen_width / 1.5), ($screen_height * 1.05) )
    $header_height = 5
    $header_width = 22
}
elseif ($screen_width -gt 1280 -or $screen_width -lt 1367) {
    Write-Host "-gt 1280"
    $main_form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( ($screen_width / 1.7), ($screen_height / 1.3) )
    $header_height = 6
    $header_width = 25
}
elseif ($screen_width -ge 1920) {
    Write-Host "-ge 1920"
    $main_form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( ($screen_width / 2.5), ($screen_height / 2) )
}
else {
    Write-Host "els"
    $main_form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( ($screen_width / 2), ($screen_height / 1.5) )
}

# set up up pannel
$panel_up = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Panel
$panel_up_height = $main_form.height / 17
$panel_up.width = $main_form.Width
$panel_up.height = $panel_up_height
$panel_up.AutoSize = $true
$panel_up.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Top
$panel_up.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(3, -2)
$panel_up.BackColor = [System.Drawing.ColorTranslator]::FromHtml("#12a9f6")
$main_form.Controls.Add($panel_up)

# set up title bar
$label_up = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label_up.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(($main_form.Width * 1.1), 80)
$label_up.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", ($main_form.width / 60), [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold, [System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit]::Pixel)
$label_up.Text = "Tool"
$label_up.AutoSize = $true
$label_up.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(($main_form.Size.Width / $header_width), ($panel_up_height / $header_height))
$label_up.ForeColor = "#FFFFFD"
$panel_up.Controls.Add($label_up)

# set up logo
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$get_logo = (Get-Item ".\LOGO.png")
$logo = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile($get_logo)
$pictureBox = New-object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$pictureBox.Image = $logo
$pictureBox.SizeMode = "Autosize"
$pictureBox.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(5, ($panel_up_height / 8))
$panel_up.controls.add($pictureBox)

# Calculate the space to leave for buttons at the bottom
$buttonSpace = $main_form.Height / 5.5  # Adjust this value as needed

# set up bottom panel 
$panel_bottom = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
$panel_bottom.width = $panel_up.Width 
$panel_bottom.height = 1.5
$panel_bottom.AutoSize = $true
$panel_bottom.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(3, ($main_form.Height - $buttonSpace))
$panel_bottom.BackColor = "#e7e7e7"
$main_form.Controls.Add($panel_bottom)

# Calculate the remaining space after the bottom panel
$remainingSpace = $main_form.Height - ($panel_bottom.Location.Y + $panel_bottom.Height)

# Calculate the vertical position for buttons in the middle of the remaining space
$buttonHeightPosition = $panel_bottom.Location.Y + $panel_bottom.Height + ($remainingSpace - 30) / 3.5

# Create and configure the first button
$button_close = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button_close.Text = "Close"
$button_close.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 30)
$button_close.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($panel_bottom.Width - 120), $buttonHeightPosition)
$button_close.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 8)  # Adjust the font size as needed
$main_form.Controls.Add($button_close)

# Create and configure the second button
$button_reboot = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button_reboot.Text = "Reboot"
$button_reboot.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 30)
$button_reboot.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($panel_bottom.Width - 240), $buttonHeightPosition)
$button_reboot.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 8)  # Adjust the font size as needed
$main_form.Controls.Add($button_reboot)

# Create and configure the third button
$button_shutdown = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button_shutdown.Text = "Shutdown"
$button_shutdown.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 30)
$button_shutdown.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($panel_bottom.Width - 360), $buttonHeightPosition)
$button_shutdown.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 8)  # Adjust the font size as needed
$main_form.Controls.Add($button_shutdown)

# Create and configure the first panel for processing information
$panel_processing = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$panel_processing.Width = $main_form.Width / 1.5
$panel_processing.Height = ($main_form.Height - $panel_up_height - $remainingSpace) - 100
$panel_processing.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(7, ($panel_up.Height * 1.9))
$panel_processing.BackColor = "#FFFFFF"
$panel_processing.Text = "Unlocking Process"
$panel_processing.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 9)
$main_form.Controls.Add($panel_processing)

# Create and configure the second panel (beside processing panel)
$panel_additional = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$panel_additional.Width = ($main_form.Width - $panel_processing.Width ) - 50
$panel_additional.Height = $panel_processing.Height
$panel_additional.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($panel_processing.Right + 18), ($panel_up.Height * 1.9))
$panel_additional.BackColor = "#FFFFFF"  # Adjust the color as needed
$panel_additional.Text = "Configuration"
$panel_additional.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 9)
$main_form.Controls.Add($panel_additional)
$main_form.Show()

function flowstep {
    param (
        $icon, $step, $new_height, [switch]$showLoadingAnimation
    )

    $pictureBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
    $pictureBox.Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($icon)
    $pictureBox.SizeMode = [System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode]::Zoom
    $pictureBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20, 20)
    $pictureBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, $new_height)

    $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(($panel_processing.Width / 2), 30)
    $label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($pictureBox.Location.X + $pictureBox.Width + 5), ($pictureBox.Location.Y + 3))

    $panel_processing.Controls.Add($pictureBox)
    $panel_processing.Controls.Add($label)

    # Pause for a short duration before moving to the next icon
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

    if ($icon -eq ".\prog.png") {
        # Add loading animation to the label
        $animation = @('.   ', '..  ', '... ', '....')
        foreach ($frame in $animation) {
            $label.Text = "$step $frame"
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
            $label.Refresh()  # Forces the label to refresh and update its display
        }
        $label.Text = $step
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "running this"
        # Clear label text if loading animation is not needed
        $label.Text = $step
    }

    # Return the PictureBox control
    return $pictureBox
}

# Step 1
$pictureBox1 = flowstep ".\cknew.png" "Start unlocking" "35"

# Step 2
# this icon represents the process is in progress
$pictureBox2 = flowstep ".\prog.png" "File authenticating" "75"

# Checking existing data
# Have some other process
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3 # assuming there this is a waiting for some process

$result = "fail"  # Change result to test fail condition
if ($result -eq "pass") {
    Write-Host "PASS"
    $pictureBox2.Visible = $false
    # Change the icon to cknew.png if the result is pass
    flowstep ".\cknew.png" "File authenticating" "75"
}
else {
    Write-Host "FAIL"
    $pictureBox2.Visible = $false
    # Change the icon to fail.png if the result is fail
    flowstep ".\fail.png" "File authenticating" "75"
}
```

i have this scrip to make the progress bar dot. How to make it keep moving while the icon is prog.png then stop and invisible once the icon change to cknew.png or fail.png?

Anyone has idea? Thanks a lot

Comment: Is this an MRE (Minimal, Reproducible Example)? The more concise the code is increases the probability of getting helpful answers.

Comment: Might I suggest checking out FoxDeploy's blog about being able to make a GUI for your script that can have a functional progress bar and also do other things in the background? Check it out [here.](https://www.foxdeploy.com/blog/part-v-powershell-guis-responsive-apps-with-progress-bars.html)